# starting more than one session for Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I tried to start two sessions for google analytics, however it is only tracked for trackerB. Is there any way to track data for two different profiles?

```
public GoogleAnalyticsTracker trackerA;
public GoogleAnalyticsTracker trackerB;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getApplication();

    trackerA = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    trackerB = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();        

    trackerA.startNewSession("UA-XXXXXX-Y", mContext);  
    trackerB.startNewSession("UA-XXXXXX-YY", mContext); 

    ....

}
```

Comment: Try and initialize with different context , or try to set trackPageView property.

Comment: GoogleAnalyticsTracker is a singleton class! you can only have one instance. That is why trackerB works only. If you can inlcude the Google library twice each time with a different name! then you may initialise `trackerA = com.library1.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance()` and `trackerB = com.library2.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance()`

Answer (score 2):

What you are calling tracker is a singleton that manages the global state.you can get the actual tracker by:

```
Context mCtx = this; // Get current context.
GoogleAnalytics myInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
Tracker myNewTracker = myInstance.getTracker("UA-XXXX-2");
```

refer to this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced#managing-trackers